# reshape image error: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: image, numpy

im=Image.open("/Users/shalinsavalia/Desktop/CNN_Numbers/Number_7.jpg")
im
im=im.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize the image
im = np.array(im)                       # convert to an array
print(im)
im2=im/np.max(im).astype(float)         # normalise input
test_image1=np.reshape(im2, [1,784])    # reshape it to our input placeholder shape

pred=(sess.run(y_predicted,
               feed_dict={
                   x:test_image1
               }))
predicted_class=np.argmax(pred)
print "Predicted class : {}" .format(predicted_class)

Error in result is:

```
Traceback  (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-161-782995cc25e1> in <module>()
    ----> 1 im = im.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
          2 im = np.array(im) 
          3 im2 = im//np.max(im).astype(float)
          4 test_image1 = np.reshape(im2, [784,4])

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to format the code?

Comment: The error is in the resize method, not reshape,  That's a `Image` issue, not a numpy one.

Comment: @user8408080 I don't know what I should do.

Comment: @ hpaulj Can you tell me how to do it?  I can't understand it.